# Remote image renderer direct link sometimes leads to 504 Gateway time-out error in case of replicated Grafana

Tags: kubernetes, grafana

Configuration:

`Kubernetes 1.24.6, Grafana 9.0.9, Grafana image renderer 3.7.0 (not the plugin, separate remote deployment)`

`Grafana` deployment replicated to 2 pods. When I set replicas to 1 everything works fine. It looks like when the renderer makes callback request (env `GF_RENDERING_CALLBACK_URL`) to `Grafana`, `Grafana's` service routes the request to the wrong pod with 50% probability.

I've set `sessionAffinity: ClientIP` on the `Grafana service`, but it didn't work either.
How can I handle this?